# Defining a Relationship on User

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm developing a package that is using the user model in the main app.

I need to add a relationship to the user model that links to one of my packages models.

How can I do this?

Create a new model in my package called user and namespace it and define the relationship here?

Is there a better way?

I do not wish for who ever uses the package to go in and add the relationship themselves to the user model.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a way to do what you want (basically edit an already defined class form within code). The 'best' way would be to create your own User class in your package and require your users to switch their auth config to use your user class. It *may* be possible using reflection (I'm not sure if reflection is only for reading from classes or whether you can also add to them, though you can definitely modify visibility of methods/variables) but it feels to me like this is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a trait for that, and ask you package's users to add it in:

```
namespace MyAwesome\Package;

trait PerishableTrait {
    public function perishables()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('MyAwesome\Package\Perishable');
    }
}
```

Then tell your users to just add this single line to their User model:

```
class User extends ... {
    use MyAwesome\Package\PerishableTrait;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, where should I put my trait?

Comment: What @josephsilber is saying is to require your users to add the trait to their own user class. Now, this is something you said you didn't want to do. However, it's a bit nicer with a trait, and if you think about it, it's how Laravel's own soft deletes work. The difference there of course is that you opt in to soft delete or not, whereas your project is kind of a requirement, which is a shame.

Comment: Thanks @alexrussel but Im asking where I should put the trait that the end users adds in, in my package? Which file should it go in?

Comment: Oh right - that can go anywhere where it makes sense for you, I'd be inclined to either put it in with the model to which relationship belongs, in a subnamespace `Traits` of that namespace, or in a package-root-level `Traits` namespace. So say your model was at `\Panthro\CoolPackage\Models\Group`, the trait should be called something like `BelongsToGroup` and be placed at one of the following: `\Panthro\CoolPackage\Models\BelongsToGroup`, `\Panthro\CoolPackage\Models\Traits\BelongsToGroup` or `\Panthro\CoolPackage\Traits\BelongsToGroup`. But that's just a suggestion - do whatever you want.